# How to be notified when a non blocking sendfile is completed

Tags: c, linux, network-programming

I am using sendfile on Linux in non blocking mode to use zero copy.
However I do not know how to deal with the following scenario.

- sendfile  (All data is buffered in kernel to be sent)
- The underlying file has been modified before all packets have been sent.
- The client will now receive the modify data instead of the original data

You can see an example of the happening here.

https://git.kernel.org/cgit/docs/man-pages/man-pages.git/patch?id=7b6a3299776b5c1c4f169a591434a855d50c68b4

My question is there a way I can be notified when all the packets have been sent instead of just when the socket is available for writing again?

I have tried polling SIOCOUTQ to check if it is zero and I still have the same problem.

Comment: 'The underlying file has been modified before all packets have been sent.' - don't let that happen.  Find out why that happens and stop it.

Comment: Is the fact that the socket is non-blocking relevant? I think sendfile returns as soon as all the input is available, regardless of whether the socket is blocking or not.

Comment: @MartinJames the problem I am having is not that file is being modified.
The problem is that I cannot determine when all the packets are sent so I can allow the file be modified.

Comment: @rici the problem is more prevalent when in non blocking mode.

Comment: @rouzier: When it comes to race conditions, more prevalent is better. Rarely present bugs are much harder to catch and fix :) Although I don't see why the problem would be more prevalent with non-blocking sockets -- non-blocking doesn't increase asynchronicity; it just means that you'll get EAGAIN from time to time and have to restart the system call. But if you've tested it, I'll believe you. Is it possible to set `SO_LINGER` and call `shutdown()`? Is it possible to add an explicit acknowledgement to your comms protocol?

Comment: Also, have you observed a case where `SIOCOUTQ` is zero, but there is still data queued for output? That sounds like a kernel bug; it would be good if you could produce a minimal test case to report it.

Comment: @rici Thank you for your feedback.

SO_LINGER and shutdown is not possible since the service allows multiple requests.

Adding an acknowledgement is a possibility.
I would prefer not to since I would prefer keep the protocol as simple as possible.

The only other solution I can think of is do not use sendfile since it is causing the problem.

Of course that does come at a price of no zero copy which would be fine at the moment since I am at the begin of this project.

I will clean up my test code and send it as a bug report.

Thank you for help with this